# Finding mean of selected entries only

Tags: matlab, mean

Consider the two vectors:

```
 v= [1 2 3 4 5 6 7]

 a=['a' 'b' 'c' 'a' 'a' 'a' 'd']
```

I want to find the mean of all entries in v whose corresponding entries in a is 'a';

i.e. test= mean(1,3,4,5)

I have tried this for a start to catch the entries:

```
for i=1:7
 if abs(char(a(i))-char(c))==0;
   test(i)=v(i);
 end
end
```

> > test

```
test =      1     0     0     4     5     6
```

PROBLEMS:

1. It is assigning 0 for entries not found
2. It is not considering last term

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using the [`ismember`](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/techdoc/ref/ismember.html) function:

> ```
> >> help ismember
>  ismember True for set member.
>     ismember(A,S) for the array A returns an array of the same size as A
>     containing 1 where the elements of A are in the set S and 0 otherwise.
>     A and S can be cell arrays of strings.
> ```

`ismember` forms your `test` vector as a logical array, assigning 1 where the character 'a' is found in your vector, and 0 where it isn't:

```
>> ismember(a, 'a')

ans =

 1     0     0     1     1     1     0
```

You can then use this as a *logical index* to extract the corresponding entries from your vector `v`:

```
>> v(ismember(a, 'a'))

ans =

     1     4     5     6
```

Finally, you can take the mean of this vector:

```
>> mean(v(ismember(a, 'a')))

ans =

  4
```

---

**EDIT**
I have realised that in your case, you can actually form your logical array in a much simpler way, using a comparison operator:

```
>> a == 'a'

ans =

     1     0     0     1     1     1     0
```

So your final line of code will look like so:

```
>> mean(v(a == 'a'))

ans =

     4
```

`ismember` is useful where you want to test for the presence of more than one character, for example if you wanted to find locations where 'a' *or* 'b' were.

Comment: what if v and a were matrices?I tried: for k=1: TotalnoOfGrids
for j=1: noOfNodes
M= mean(Allvalues{k}(char(Allquants{k}(j))==char(mostCommonLetters{k})));
Ms{k}=MyPerfectAverage; something wrong. @Bill Chaeatham

Comment: If v and a are matrices of equal size, all the above code will work but you will need to vectorise a first - i.e. call `mean(v(a(:) == 'a'))`

Comment: my v is:[1x10 double]    [1x10 double]    [1x10 double]    [1x10 double] thanks @Bill Chaeatham. I am trying to solve but a help is appriciated

Comment: I see - you have a cell array. You might be better off asking this as a new question because it will become confusing explaining cell array operations in these comment fields!

Comment: OK got ur point.I used mat2cell.but what I need is mean of every row alone.SO the result should be 1*k and not as now k*1