# Finding mean in cell with condition

Tags: matlab, mean

I have the following:

```
a='abaacacbaa'    'abaaabaaaa'    'dcdcbbcccc'    'acaaaaabba'

v=[1x10 double]    [1x10 double]    [1x10 double]    [1x10 double]
v{1}=0.0064    0.4009   -0.0125   -0.0913    0.5707    0.0442    0.5210    0.3174   -0.2201    0.0570

letter={1x1 cell}    {1x1 cell}    {1x1 cell}    {1x1 cell}
letter{1}='a'


Here i=4 and j=10
```

I want to find for each i the mean of entries in v whos corresponding entries in a is equal to letter{i}.

using as @Bill Cheatham mentioned [Finding mean of selected entries only](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10070176/finding-mean-of-selected-entries-only)

the equation:

```
   mean(v(a == 'a'))
```

so I tried:

```
  for k=1: 4
   for j=1: 10 
     M= mean(v{k}(char(a{k}(j))==char(letter{k})));
     Ms{k}=M;
    end
  end
```

also tried to use

```
   a(:) and
    mat2cell(v)
```

So the result should be :
Ms= [mean of row 1}    {mean of row 2}     {mean of row 3}    {mean of row 4}

put the brackets to make seperation here obvious

thanks

Comment: It sounds like you should just leave off the j loop and then just char(a{k}) == char(letter{k})...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As suggested by Dan, leaving off the j loop solved the problem